# Which is correct work or worked?

Tags: descriptive-grammar

Which sentence is correct:

- It would be a good idea if you work hard.
- It would be a good idea if you worked hard.

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Please add some context to explain what you are trying to express by either statement.

Comment: I believe you are trying to choose between the present subjunctive and past subjunctive (poorly named because it doesn't actually refer to the past). Both seem OK to me, but others may disagree.

Answer (score -1):

Even though you are talking about the future, "worked" is much more common in this case, perhaps because it 'just sounds better' with "would be". "Will be/work" may even be more 'correct', but the other is what is used.